# Slice a df by passing column names from another df

Tags: pandas

I would like to slice my df. The column names from my df that I would like to keep are given as values in another df column.

**df code:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': ['abcde','abcde','abcde']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['B']=[0,0,0]
df['C']=[1,2,3]
df['D']=['abFC=0.01#%sdadf','12fdak*4%FC=-0.035faf,dd43','FC=0.5fasff']
df

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
    A   B   C   D
0   abcde   0   1   abFC=0.01#%sdadf
1   abcde   0   2   12fdak*4%FC=-0.035faf,dd43
2   abcde   0   3   FC=0.5fasff
```

**df with column values to slice:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Slice_Vals': ['A','B','C']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Slice_Vals
0   A
1   B
2   C
```

**desired output:**

```
    A       B   C   
0   abcde   0   1   
1   abcde   0   2   
2   abcde   0   3
```

Comment: `df.loc[:, df2.Slice_Vals]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should achieve what you want: `df[df2.Slice_Vals]`

Outputs:

```
A   B   C
0   abcde   0   1
1   abcde   0   2
2   abcde   0   3
```